# Why doesn't Spyder obey my IPython config file?

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, anaconda, spyder

This used to work, but now it doesn't, in IPython 4.2.0 and Spyder 2.3.9 from Anaconda. Argh.

If I get the IPython config it looks correct, as though it read the file correctly:

```
get_ipython().config
Out[1]: 
{'IPCompleter': {'greedy': True},
 'IPKernelApp': {'exec_lines': ['%pylab qt']},
 'InlineBackendConfig': {},
 'InteractiveShell': {'xmode': 'Plain'},
 'InteractiveShellApp': {'exec_lines': ['from __future__ import division',
   'from __future__ import print_function',
   'from __future__ import with_statement',
   'from numpy import set_printoptions',
   'set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=4)',
   'from sympy import init_printing',
   'init_printing(forecolor="White")'],
  'pylab': 'auto'},
 'StoreMagics': {'autorestore': True},
 'ZMQInteractiveShell': {'autocall': 0, 'banner1': ''}}
```

So it's supposed to have future division and numpy suppression, but it actually doesn't:

```
division
Out[1]: _Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)

4/5
Out[2]: 0

np.get_printoptions()
Out[3]: 
{'edgeitems': 3,
 'formatter': None,
 'infstr': 'inf',
 'linewidth': 75,
 'nanstr': 'nan',
 'precision': 8,
 'suppress': False,
 'threshold': 1000}

eps = np.finfo(float).eps; x = np.arange(4.); x**2 - (x + eps)**2
Out[4]: 
array([ -4.93038066e-32,  -4.44089210e-16,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00])
```

This is what it should do:

```
from __future__ import division

division
Out[2]: _Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)

4/5
Out[3]: 0.8

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

eps = np.finfo(float).eps; x = np.arange(4.); x**2 - (x + eps)**2
Out[5]: array([-0., -0.,  0.,  0.])

np.get_printoptions()
Out[6]: 
{'edgeitems': 3,
 'formatter': None,
 'infstr': 'inf',
 'linewidth': 75,
 'nanstr': 'nan',
 'precision': 8,
 'suppress': True,
 'threshold': 1000}
```

Regular IPython works correctly (`C:\Anaconda2\python.exe C:\Anaconda2\cwp.py C:\Anaconda2 "C:/Anaconda2/python.exe" "C:/Anaconda2/Scripts/ipython-script.py"`)

Jupyter QTConsole works correctly (`C:\Anaconda2\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda2\cwp.py C:\Anaconda2 "C:/Anaconda2/pythonw.exe" "C:/Anaconda2/Scripts/jupyter-qtconsole-script.py"`)

Comment: Is it related to [this bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3354) in spyder?

Comment: @PeterBrittain No, but that's a good workaround!

Comment: The one probably annoying answer (no one wants to re-install) may be onto something.  Anaconda 4.2 was riddled with bugs.  I got involved on github posting issues and they were very good about looking into them though they probably did have to prioritize against planned releases and other peoples' issues I am sure.  Anaconda 4.3.1 is now out.  You may want to try an upgrade and see if your issue gets fixed.  You could also click the link to the spyder bug and follow it up to the project to post your issue for help.

Comment: some other things to try:  conda update conda and conda update anaconda to update these components.  Then conda update spyder, but make sure to update in this order or you could corrupt spyder and then see it not working.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure what is the problem either
I was having the same issue

but mine was fixed when I uninstalled anaconda with EVERYTHING including its python bit
granted I saved the settings and profile and stuff

and reinstalled

Hope that helps, if its an option at all